# arrange multiple squares as one big circle in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, geometry

I try to arrange multiple square pictures on a canvas so that they form a circle which is completely covered with these elements like on this picture:

[image]

[See original here (slide three)](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/ng-interactive/2015/oct/19/homan-square-chicago-police-detainees)

How can I compute the x and y coordinates and the size of each element given n elements and a fix radius?

thanks in advance!

P.S.: probably I'll use [pixi.js](http://www.pixijs.com/) for this

Comment: `size = 2 * π * r ** 2 / n`

Comment: @JonasW. why the factor of 2?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog good question...

Comment: Not as easy as it seems because in general n squares will not fit symmetrically in the circle. This will be especially noticeable for small n.

Comment: You probably mean fixed square size, not 'fix radius' ?

Answer (score 0):

**My suggestion:**

The question is related to the "Gauss circle problem", that has no simple solution.

So I would choose a too large radius, to be sure to cover at least `n` squares (such as the smallest integer such that π(r-1)² ≥ n). Then generate all (x, y) pairs within that radius (x²+y² ≤ r²), keeping the value of x²+y² for each.

Next, sort by increasing x²+y², and keep the n smallest. This will fill a regular circle, with extra pixels on the outer layer until the count is n.